# Teamcity separate test result viewer

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-7.0, teamcity-7.1

Is there a way to show different reports inside TeamCity build page for different types of tests?

We have the only one Gradle build for all checks (and we don't want to have separate builds for every check type). But we want to show separate test reports for every type of tests (UI, unit, etc).